# Decreasing number of visitors per day

Tags: discusión

During the last weeks I've been concerned about the number of visitors per day to this site. If I remember well, about one or two weeks ago there were 130 visitors per day, some days ago were only 128, but as of now (december 23th), this amount is only 102.

Is there something concrete we can do about this?

Comment: I think it's quite normal for site usage to drop off considerably right after the site goes public.  If the site material is worth while, it will begin to increase again.

Comment: Also keep in mind this is the holiday season; many people (like me) won't be around their computers as much until after the first of the year.

Comment: Activity has definitely gone way down lately, hopefully it's just the holidays. It's always good to share the site with your friends and continue to populate it with good content to attract people from search engines.

Comment: Now only 81 as today.

Comment: Publicize! Tell your friends! Post on forums you use that are about language or about any country where Spanish is spoken! If you use Lonely Planet Thorn Tree or Couch Surfing groups - let people know about us!

Comment: Now that the holidays are over, it's quite apparent that our traffic is increasing again. Yay!

Comment: Definitely moving up instead of down!

Comment: Number of users is moving up BTW!

Comment: Now 166 per day!

Comment: Broke 200 per day for the first time.

Comment: 320 per day!! :D

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, holidays (and weekends) can definitely affect participation.

In general, though, there are a few things you can do to help promote the site:

- Tell others about it. Do you know someone who's learning Spanish? Invite them to the site! Are there any events or communities in your area where it'd make sense to mention Spanish SE?
- Continue posting quality questions and answers. Stack Exchange sites are indexed well by Google and having answers to someone's question is a great way to get that someone to come back.
- Strengthen the community of the site by participating in chat, on meta, or editing posts to make them better and leaving comments where appropriate.